# Einstein Maxwell Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, conventions, maxwell-equations, reissner-nordstrom-metric

If  I take the Lagrangian 
\begin{eqnarray} L= \frac{1}{2}  R *1 - \frac{1}{2} F\wedge *F 
\end{eqnarray}
I found $$ds^2 = -(1-\frac{2M}{R}  +\frac{Q^2}{2r^2} )dt^2 + (1-\frac{2M}{R}  +\frac{Q^2}{2r^2} )^{-1}dr^2 +r^2d\Omega^2   $$  and $$E = \frac{Q}{r^2}.$$

On the other hand, If  I take the Lagrangian 
\begin{eqnarray}
L= \frac{1}{2}  R *1 -   F\wedge *F  
\end{eqnarray}
without $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of Maxwell term,
I found $$ds^2 = -(1-\frac{2M}{R}  +\frac{Q^2}{r^2} )dt^2 + (1-\frac{2M}{R}  +\frac{Q^2}{r^2} )^{-1}dr^2 +r^2d\Omega^2   $$  and $$E = \frac{Q}{r^2}.$$

Which one of these Lagrangian is correct? 
I can show that first one is equivalent to $L= \frac{1}{2}  R  - \frac{1}{4} F_{ab}F^{ab} $.
I think the first one correct, but there is a $\frac{1}{2}  $ factor in the metric as a coefficient of $\frac{Q^2}{r^2}$. Is this factor  important for the definition of Reissner Nordstrom metric?
If I product all the Lagrangian  by 2, does it change anything for gravitational or qauntum fields point of view?

Comment: You could do the variation of the action and check which lagrangian has the correct prefactor in the maxwell equations.

Comment: Is there any constraint on the Lagrangian level?

Comment: I don't think so. Such level constraints usually come from the lagrangian being not completely gauge invariant. Sometimes this ambiguity can be fixed by using a level constraint. At the classical level, this lagrangian is gauge invariant, so such a problem does not seem to occur. This does not take into account the problem of gravitational anomalies though. I am no expert, so i couldnt say about that.